# Global Security Group AD Issue

Tags: windows-server-2003, group-policy

This is on Windows Server 2003.

I created a testgroup and add the testuserA on it. When I created a folder that has permission for testgroup, i try to log in to the testuserA's computer, and obviously I accessed the folder.

But when i log on to TestuserB, which is not a member of testgroup, i can even access the folder that has permission for testgroup only

i also tried to remove TestUserA to the testgroup member, but after doing this, i have an access to the folder again.

Do i need to create a Group Policy for this, for me to have a create folder permission to assigned user only.  if i Group policy need to apply, please help me what would be the setup for this or how would i create Group policy.

Comment: Is there any other groups that have permission that folder? Such as the "Everyone" group?

Comment: i already remove that, and also the MACHINE\user...

Comment: I only included 'ADministrator, Creato OWner, System and also testUserA'

Comment: @ck1201: By 'access' do you mean that you can copy the folder's contents?

Comment: Group policies have nothing to do with ACL's on directories.